# What is the purpose of `assets`, `category` and `bookmarks` metadata in Next.js?

Tags: web, next.js, frontend, seo, metadata

I was studying the [Next.js docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/generate-metadata#viewport) and these are listed as options for generateMetadata. What are they used for? How do you use them? Who uses them?

- Category

```
<meta name="category" content="technology" />
```

- Bookmarks

```
<link rel="bookmarks" href="https://nextjs.org/13" />
```

- Assets

```
<link rel="assets" href="https://nextjs.org/assets" />
```

I can't find the right google search terms to find concrete answers. Chatgpt on the other hand basically returns this for all three of them.

> It's possible that the code snippet you provided is part of a larger context or a custom implementation specific to a certain application or website. Without more information or context, it's challenging to provide a definitive answer about the purpose of this specific code. If you have additional details or surrounding code, I may be able to offer more insights.

Answer (score 0):

It is listed [here](https://gist.github.com/whitingx/3840905). And it appears to have no functional use at all except perhaps for self-documentation purposes.

> For what it's worth, most of the "Basic HTML Meta Tags" have no uses.